# Significato di "abbentarsi"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Un uomo entra nello sgabuzzino, poi un altro, un altro, un altro ancora, finché perde il conto. Qualcuno si svacca sulla branda di fronte alla sua, qualcuno su una rete che scricchiola. Tonfi di mobili spostati, sospiri. Gente che si spoglia – sentore di ascelle. Una, due, dieci concitate voci maschili che si accavallano. Le voci appartengono a un branco di tagliagole privi di scrupoli e assetati di sangue. Parlano – con dialetti diversi e a volte incomprensibili – di incazzature, mazzate, duemila pezze che Agnello deve consegnare a qualcuno altrimenti gli mozzano il naso e glielo ficcano su per il sedere, cosí la sentirà veramente la puzza al naso, quello sparagnino arricchito e arrepezzato. Parlano di polismen che trovènno una vagliona di nove anni. Diamante non osa nemmeno respirare. Qualcuno impreca, ordinando agli altri di **abbentarsi**, ma nessuno gli dà retta.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "abbentarsi" in questo brano? Non ho trovato questo verbo in nessun dizionario. Immagino  si tratti di un vocabolo di origine dialettale.

Answer (score 2):

In questo articolo di blog intitolato [*Riflessioni sul dialetto*](https://digilander.libero.it/marino50/Dialetto/Riflessioni/Riflessioni.htm) si può leggere

> **Sbentàre, ventàre, abbentàre** 
>  Sbentàre, ventàre, abbentàre Questa volta parliamo di tre
>   verbi che si somigliano un po', ma che indicano tre azioni
>   diversissime. Il primo potremmo tradurlo forzatamente con l'italiano
>   evaporare, ma il significato può anche essere quello di perdere il gas
>   (ad esempio nel caso di una bibita gasata lasciata aperta), perdere
>   l'odore, il sapore o altre caratteristiche organolettiche.  Anche
>   ventàre potrebbe essere tradotto  forzatamente con appurare, ma
>   l'esatto significato è un po' più difficile da spiegare. Praticamente
>   significa farsi scoprire di essere in possesso di un  oggetto, un
>   utensile, un qualcosa che potrebbe servire ad altri che potrebbero
>   chiederlo in prestito; da qui l'esortazione: " 'Un tu fare ventàre
>   sinnò t' 'u circa' ". **Abbentàre, invece, significa semplicemente
>   riposarsi un po' dopo uno sforzo.**

Abbentare significa riposarsi dopo uno sforzo, una fatica.

Qualcuno impreca ordinando agli altri di riposarsi.

Sempre nello stesso articolo viene riportato un altro significato per abbentarsi, cioè avventarsi, anche se non mi sembra adatto al contesto citato.

> **S' abbentare**
>  Verbo molto simile all'italiano avventarsi, in realtà, almeno nel dialetto caccurese, ha un doppio significato. **Il
>   primo, meno usato, è quello di scagliarsi violentemente contro
>   qualcuno, ma il secondo, molto più usato, almeno un tempo, sta a
>   indicare il riposo, una sosta mentre si trasporta un peso gravoso o
>   mentre si sta eseguendo un lavoro estremamente faticoso.** "Abbentate
>   'nu pocu! ..... Si, mo m'abbentu."

Comment: Si tratta di calabrese?

Comment: _"Qualcuno impreca ordinando agli altri di riposarsi."_ mi sembra un po' strano... azzardo l'ipotesi che in questo caso al posto di "riposarsi" sia meglio utilizzare "calmarsi" o "darsi una calmata".

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Si tratta della stanza da letto di tutti questi personaggi, cioè, la stanza dove, almeno in teoria, vanno a dormire. Quindi mi sembra plausibile che il significato sia quello spiegato nella risposta.